# Is NSMutableArray recursive in releasing it's items?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios, memory-management

If I have a 2 dimensional NSMutableArray eg,

```
board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:boardHeight];
for (int y = 0; y < boardHeight; y++) {
    NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:boardWidth];

    for (int x = 0; x < boardWidth; x++) {
        [row insertObject:@"A string"];             
    }

    [board insertObject:row atIndex:y];
    [row release];
}
```

and I do

```
[board release];
```

Does that recursively release the array? Or do I have to manually go into the array and release each row?

If it does, and the object inserted into each row were a custom object, is there anything special I have to think about when writing the dealloc method for the custom object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything will just work fine. The array will retain the objects when they are added and released when removed or the array is deallocated.

No extra work on that part.

Answer (score 1):

When `board` is ready to be deallocated, it will send the `release` message to each object in itself.  Even if those objects are `NSArray`s, they will still be `release`d; and if those arrays are now ready to be deallocated, they will send `release` to their members, etc.

Your class should implement `dealloc` normally -- `release` any ivars that you hold a strong reference to before calling `[super dealloc]`.